# Correspondence between $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

There is a one-to-one correspondence between irreducible $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})-$representations and $\mathbb{C} \times \{ \text{irreducible }  \mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C}) \text{ representations} \}.$

I'm having difficulty forming an explicit map between these two sets. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Decompose $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ into a direct sum of subalgebras, its centre and $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, suppose $V$ is an irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{C}).$ Then $V$ is necessarily an irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C}),$ so why is it necessary to map $V$ to $(a,V)$ where $a \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ is not in fact the same as $V$ (which stands for a representation, not just a vector space), but a _restriction_ of $V$. Similarly restriction of $V$ to the centre of $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ gives a representation of that centre, which is a $1$-dimensional commutative Lie algebra, on the vector space. At a Lie algebra element spanning the centre, such a representation is necessarily multiplication by some scalar, and this scalar gives you your value $a$. So the correspondence in fact depends on a choice of an element spanning the centre

Comment: Thanks very much for clarifying that, if you post this as an answer I will accept it.